# SQL Server: 32-bit instance on 64-bit server?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, 32bit-64bit

Is there a way to create a 32-bit instance of SQL Server on SQL Server 2008 x64 without installing SQL Server 2008 x32?  And if I have to install SQL 2008 x32; is there a problem installing both 32 and 64 on the same server?

I have some FoxPro datasources that I am needing to access via linked server.
There are no 64-bit foxpro drivers that I know of.

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Answer (score 2):

yes, you can install 32 bit sql on a 64 bit machine without issue.  We've done it many times.  You can also have a 32 bit install sitting side by side with a 64 bit install; again no problems and yes we've done it.

You can even set up linked servers between the two if necessary.

The only way to create a 32 bit instance is to run the 32 bit installer.

Answer (score 0):

The 32 bit installer will fail if you run it on a 64 bit machine.  What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: No it won't - it may not run optimally but it will still run.  I inherited a setup exactly like this (and quickly upgraded to 64bit Sql Server)

Comment: I disagree with these downvotes.  I have the 32 bit installer right here failing on a 64 bit machine (sql server 2008 R2).

Comment: That doesnt mean that it won't work, just that you are having a configuration problem that is preventing it from working for you.

Comment: Well it fails out of the box and on a fresh machine.  I won't be encouraging people to hack a 32 bit install onto a 64 bit machine; it must be discouraged and not a default setting for good reason.